# AWS: Restoring database snapshot to different environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic, amazon-rds

I've a webapp hosted on AWS. This has Electric Beanstalk, with EC2 and then a RDS Postgres database at the bottom.

There's prod, UAT and staging environments and databases.

I want to take a recent snapshot of the prod database (well I've done that) and restore it on the staging database, as the current staging environment is a bit out of data wise.

Yet when I go to restore snapshots in the staging database, I can only restore those which were taken on the staging database.

Is there any way to restore the prod snapshot which I've made to the staging database?

Answer (score 1):

Restoring a snapshot simply creates a new RDS instance.
So if you restore the prod DB snapshot to staging then you will be creating a new RDS instance with the restored data in it.

- If both of the RDS instances are in the same aws account then
  You will either have to delete/rename the staging DB and then restore the prod DB
- If both of the RDS instances are in different/separate AWS account then you can share the snapshot in other account and restore it there
  Here is the aws official doc : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-update-cross-account-snapshot-sharing/

Ps: Another option can be, using mysqldump to take backup from prod and then restoring it to the staging instance

Comment: They're both in the same account. I certainly don't want to touch the live prod DB also. I think I just want staging now to point at the new RDS instance. I'm just having trouble finding where the EC2 instance says what database backs it.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? You can try checking your app configuration for the connection strings with your rds endpoint name mentioned in it.

Comment: Hi, did this solve your problem . If yes, would you please accept the answer